# CodeIgniter image cropping - image not affected by crop() parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, gd, crop

I have this model to crop the user's image

```
function crop_avatar()
{
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    //get current avatar
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_profiles', array('id' => $id));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $j[$row->avatar] = $row->avatar;
    }

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd';
    $config['source_image'] = '.' . substr("$row->avatar", 18);
    $config['x_axis'] = '10';
    $config['y_axis'] = '60';
    $this->load->library('image_lib');      
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

//      print_r($config);


}
```

which generates this array (via print_r)

```
Array
(
    [image_library] => gd
    [source_image] => ./images/avatars/b0b623057.jpg
    [x_axis] => 10
    [y_axis] => 60
)
```

For some reason unknown to me - there's no cropping going on. The original image passes straight thru this model, and is unchanged.

I do have GD on my server -- any ideas what might be wrong here?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define the width and height you want your image to be cropped at.

The `x_axis` and `y_axis` config values are the point in your existing image where the crop should start.

To put it another way, you need 4 measurements to crop the image : where to start vertically (`y_axis`), where to start horizontally (`x_axis`), where to end vertically (`height`) and where to end horizontally (`width`)

If one of the dimensions of your cropped image is the same as that of your original image, don't forget to set `maintain_ratio` to `false`

Comment: you saved my day - thanks so much for your tip -- too bad the CI docs omit the info you provided

Comment: I think it would help to mention that "where to start" is relative to the upper left hand corner, and "where to end" is relative to the coordinates of x_axis and y_axis. In other words, "where to end" with respect to the upper left hand corner, is actually the sums (y_axis + height) and (x_axis + width). Maybe that's obvious to some people, but it's not to me, given that in geometry the origen of a graph is usually in the lower left hand corner and that positive values for y go up rather than down as they do in this case.